# Please check my proof of this elementary covector result

Tags: proof-verification, solution-verification

I would appreciate it if someone could look over my proof and verify that it's correct. The question:

> Let $f$ be a $k$-covector on vector space V. Let $u_1,\dots u_k\in V$ and $v_1,\dots,v_k\in V$ be related via
>   $$u_j=\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_j^iv_i, j=1\dots k$$
>   for some $k\times k$ matrix $A=[\alpha_j^i]$. Proof that
>   $$f(u_1,\dots u_k)=\det(A)f(v_1,\dots,v_k)$$

My attempt:
$$\begin{align}
f(u_1,\dots,u_k)&=f(\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_1^iv_i,\dots,\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_k^iv_i)\\
&=\sum_{i_1=1}^k\alpha_1^{i_1}f(v_{i_1},\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_2^iv_i,\dots,\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_k^iv_i)\\
&=\dots\\
&=\sum_{i_1=1}^k\alpha_1^{i_1}\dots\sum_{i_k=1}^k\alpha_k^{i_k}f(v_{i_1},\dots,v_{i_k})\\
&=\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\alpha_1^{\sigma(1)}\dots\alpha_k^{\sigma(k)}f(v_{\sigma(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma(k)})\\
&=\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\alpha_1^{\sigma(1)}\dots\alpha_k^{\sigma(k)}\text{sgn}(\sigma) f(v_1,\dots,v_k)\\
&=f(v_1,\dots,v_k)\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\alpha_1^{\sigma(1)}\dots\alpha_k^{\sigma(k)}\\
&=\det(A)f(v_1,\dots,v_k)
\end{align}$$
Where I use from top to bottom:

1. substitution
2. $f$ is linear in the first argument
3. $f$ is linear in each of its arguments
4. Write this out
5. Since $f$ is alternating, $f(v_1\dots v_k)=0$ if $v_i=v_j$ for some $i,j$, so we only need to sum over all permutations (since the other terms will be $0$)
6. Use the other defining property of an alternating function

And from here it should be clear. I'm especially interested in the validity of step $5$, and I'm curious for other ways of working this out.

The reason I'm asking for verification is because this is some pretty basic stuff, and I want to be sure that I can atleast work with the basics before continuing (I'm self studying from the book 'An introduction to manifolds' by Loring W. Tu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof looks fine to me. I'd replace "it's" by "its" in step 3. :) And for step 5, I might say:

"The sum over all multi-indices $(i_1, \ldots, i_k)$ can be broken into two sums, one of multi-indices that have repeated indices, and one over multi-indices without repetitions; each of the latter group is a permutation of $(1, \ldots, k)$, and each permutation appears only once."

just to make the jump to a sum over $S_k$ a little clearer